# Question about jQuery source code (addClass)

Tags: jquery

Can you explain the following logic inside "if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ))" inside addClass? I don't understand what its purpose. Thanks.

```
addClass: function( value ) {

        var classNames, i, l, elem,
            setClass, c, cl;

        if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
            return this.each(function( j ) {
                jQuery( this ).addClass( value.call(this, j, this.className) );
            });
        }

        if ( value && typeof value === "string" ) {
            classNames = value.split( rspace );

            for ( i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
                elem = this[ i ];

                if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                    if ( !elem.className && classNames.length === 1 ) {
                        elem.className = value;

                    } else {
                        setClass = " " + elem.className + " ";

                        for ( c = 0, cl = classNames.length; c < cl; c++ ) {
                            if ( !~setClass.indexOf( " " + classNames[ c ] + " " ) ) {
                                setClass += classNames[ c ] + " ";
                            }
                        }
                        elem.className = jQuery.trim( setClass );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return this;
    },
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the [API page](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).  You'll see that there is a way of calling `addClass` that passes a function as the first argument.  The function receives the element and returns class names to be added:

> A function returning one or more space-separated class names to be added. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old class value as arguments. Within the function, `this` refers to the current element in the set.

So you can do this:

```
$('.someElements').addClass(function(i, currentClass) {
    return 'newClass' + i;
});
```

The first element selected will have the class `newClass0` added, the second `newClass1`, etc.

---

With the code you posted:

```
if (jQuery.isFunction(value)) {
    return this.each(function (j) {
        jQuery(this).addClass(value.call(this, j, this.className));
    });
}
```

This says:

1. If the first argument was a function
2. Loop through all the elements selected
3. For each of them, call the function with the element as the context (the `this` value), the position in the loop as the first argument and the `className` property as the second argument).
4. Then call the `addClass` method with the result of step #3.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Why this refer to the elements selected?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at documentation, there can be a function inside.

> .addClass( function(index, currentClass) ) 
>   function(index,
>   currentClass)A function returning one or more space-separated class
>   names to be added. Receives the index position of the element in the
>   set and the old class value as arguments. Within the function, this
>   refers to the current element in the set.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/). It is used to test if the passed argument is a function that returns a space separated list of classes

Answer (score 0):

You can use function in .addClass() function like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").addClass(function(i) {
        return "li" + i;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
 function addClass(elem, className) {
        if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
            elem.className += ' ' + className;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You havn't explained anything.